# HTML Form submission Double URL Encode from %20 to %2520

Tags: java, php, html, forms, hyperlink

I am creating a simple dropdown form using data from my database. In the dropdown menu I am displaying options to the user and URL encoding the value of each option so that upon submission spaces are rendered as %20 to pass in a hyperlink. However, after submitting my form it seems to encode my spaces from %20 to %2520 (%20 encoded again). This creates varying hyperlinks to the same content on my site and is not optimal since these links vary from the %20 links I am using to refer to the same content elsewhere.

I've echoed the option value to test it out and it appears to be correct and being stored as %20 while in the form. For the life of me I cannot figure out what about form submission is causing the value to get encoded a second time. Any help is appreciated!

I am using PHP to pull values from my database and BootStrap v3.0 if that makes any difference.

**Form Code:**

```
<form name="topitems" id="topitems" action="best-items.php" method="get">
    <strong>Best Items:</strong><br>
    <select name="items" id="items" onChange="document.topitems.submit()"> 
      <option value="option1">Select an Item</option>
<?php
   require ('start_connection.php'); // Connect to the db.
   // Make the query:
   $query = "SELECT DISTINCT items FROM table WHERE displayed = 'Yes' ORDER BY items ASC";      
   $results = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $query); // Run the query.

   if ($results) { // If it ran OK, display the records.

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
       echo "<option value=".rawurlencode($row[items]).">" . $row['items'] . "</option>";

}?>
     </select>
</form>
<?php
    mysqli_free_result ($results); // Free up the resources.    
  }
?>
```

Comment: So it appears that on form submission a GET request will encode the value it is passing to a URL (which is causing the double encoding).        Is there any way to prevent this? - RFC1866, page 46; HTML 4.x section 17.13.3) state:
If the method is "get" and the action is an HTTP URI, the user agent takes the value of action, appends a `?' to it, then appends the form data set, encoded using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content type.

Comment: My other workaround is writing the entire url for each item to the option value, but that seems like a ton more code to be generated dynamically each time. I use %20 on static links on my site so it would be ideal to not use the combination of + from HTTP URI requests with GET in addition to %20.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the request which is fired will be encoding again your text/url. So as html encoding of `space` is `%20` and of `%` is `%25`. So i hope that you will be getting the url as `%2520` instead of `%20`.

So to resolve remove the manual encoding done and let the request handle the encoding.

I hope its clear and working for you.!